# Stable Diffusion Model Fails to Load. What's causing the error?

Tags: memory, python, git

Seems like a memory related issue but I thought my system should be able to run Stable Diffusion. Iam using **Ideapad Gaming 3i with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 (4GB VRAM) + 8GB physical memory**

I have **no technical knowledge about Python, Git etc**. I have simply followed the following steps as shown on [this webpage](https://www.dexerto.com/tech/how-to-install-stable-diffusion-2124809/).

> Installed Python 3.10.6.

> Installed Git.

> Cloned Web-UI1.

> Downloaded Stable Diffusion <v1-5-pruned-emaonly.ckpt>

> Set up Web-UI1.

The final step is to `run webui-user.bat`, but that returns the error (Screenshot attached)

Please help me with a solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the error message?

Comment: Could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired. Copy/paste, select then Ctrl/K to format as 'code'

Comment: The error clearly says `OutOfMemoryError` and goes on to say you have 3.44 GB used of 4GB. You still need some used by your OS and other programs so 4GB may well not be enough for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The file `v1-5-pruned-emaonly.ckpt` is also 4.27GB and the [Stable Diffusion page at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion) states "Stable Diffusion is a latent diffusion model, a kind of deep generative artificial neural network. Its code and model weights have been released publicly,[8] and it **can run on most consumer hardware equipped with a modest GPU with at least 8 GB VRAM.**"

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough VRAM to run Stable Diffusion. At least now without some configuration.

The [Stable Diffusion page at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion) states

> Stable Diffusion is a latent diffusion model, a kind of deep generative artificial neural network. Its code and model weights have been released publicly,[8] and it **can run on most consumer hardware equipped with a modest GPU with at least 8 GB VRAM.**

There is some guidelines to using SD on 4-6GB VRAM at [Okuha Stable Diffusion Requirements – Hardware & Software](https://okuha.com/stable-diffusion-requirements/) but apparently has some pretty significant trade-offs such as being slow or having very low resolution images.

> - Edit webui-user.bat (after installing Stable Diffusion locally)
>
>   - After **COMMANDLINE_ARGS=** (enter your desired parameters):
>   - Example: **COMMANDLINE_ARGS=--medvram**
>   - If you have 4GB-6GB VRAM, use **--medvram**.
>   - If you have 2GB VRAM, use **--lowvram**.
>   - You can also try **--xformers**, as many users have seen great results with that, some reporting 4x faster results than with
>     **--medvram**.
>     If you are getting ‘Out of memory’ errors on either of these, add **--always-batch-cond-uncond** to the other arguments.

But it may still be that a 1650 is not good enough as there is a caveat:

> If you get a green or black screen instead of generated images, you
> might have a card that doesn’t support half-precision floating point
> numbers (**a known problem on 16xx cards**), use --precision full
> --no-half in addition to other flags (this enables the model to take more space in VRAM).